# Adding files into zip adds the folders containing the files

Tags: php, zip

So I have a directory which contains at its root a `files` folder and inside it a `test` folder containing  txt files, I then have this php code:

```php
    function displayZip($name)
   $zip = new ZipArchive();
   $filename = "files/$name.zip";

  if ($zip->open($filename, ZipArchive::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
      exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");
  }

  $dir = "files/$name/";
  createZip($zip, $dir);

  $zip->close();
  rmdir("files/$name");
 }

 function createZip($zip,$dir, $name){
  if (is_dir($dir)){

    if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
       while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){

         // If file
         if (is_file($dir.$file)) {
            if($file != '' && $file != '.' && $file != '..'){
               $zip->addFile($dir.$file);
            }
        }
   }
closedir($dh);
}
}
```

Which takes a name for the zip under the `$name` variable then specifies the full path under `$filename` then creates the zip archive, it then calls the createZip function which opens the directory of the same name of the zip and then adds the files under this directory inside the zip, however when I call `displayZip(’test’)` and then open the created zip, I see that it added the `files/test/` folders inside it. So my question here is:

1. where in the code does it add these folders, is it at the `addFile` line with `$dir.$file` part?
2. What could I do to only get the files inside the zip?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the `ZipArchive` adds the folders to the archive. You can remove the folders by specifying a "localname" as a second parameter in `addFile()`. That "localname" will be the structure within the zip archive. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php for details.

The rmdir is likely not working because because the directory isn't empty.

Comment: Thanks alot, it fixed my issue! You were also right about the rmdir, I had forgotten about this error...